# Very confused? Derivative or chain rule?

Tags: calculus

I have a bunch of questions like this

[image: question]

I have been learning about the chain rule, derivatives, the extended power rule, product rule, exponent rule, etc. But so far my book has not had any similar examples like this so I am confused as to where I begin. Do I use the chain rule? If so where do I start? Is there a particular "name" for these or just "finding the derivative?" I really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: You might have an easier time figuring this out if you rewrite it as $f(x) = (4x^2+4)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any method that works.  A convenient feature of mathematics is that it works no matter which (valid) method you use.

For this kind of problem, it is easiest to ask yourself, "how many 'places' is there an $x$?"  By "places", I mean "numerator and denominator".  If there are $x$s in both places, then you (probably) will prefer to use the quotient rule.  If there are $x$s only in the numerator, then there is no quotient and the result is straightforward.  If there are $x$s only in the denominator, then the quotient rule will be very easy; the lack of $x$s in the numerator makes the derivative of the numerator especially simple.  Similarly, the chain rule makes it easy in the case that there are only $x$s in the denominator since this is "some function of $x$" raised to "some negative power".

Consider $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$.  We may apply the quotient rule: $$g'(x) = \frac{f(x) \cdot 0 - 1 \cdot f'(x)}{f(x)^2} = \frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$ or we may apply the chain rule: $$g'(x) = \left( f(x)^{-1} \right)' = (-1)f(x)^{-2}f'(x) = \frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$.  We get the same answer either way, so it doesn't matter which method we use.

Some people find it easier to go one way or the other.  It doesn't matter which way is chosen as long as the method is applied correctly.

Comment: So helpful! Thanks! So am I correct in thinking the answer is 8x/(4x^2 + 4)^2?

Comment: @user3247128: Which rule do you prefer to use?  (I.e., which one did you use to get your proposed answer?)

Comment: I used the quotient rule - still getting to grips with the chain rule. I got to (4x^2) + (4) x (0) - (1) x (8x)/(4x^2+4)^2, not sure if I simplified it correctly?

Comment: @user3247128: Don't forget the "-" in front of the "(1)".

Comment: You are very kind to help me out so much, I really appreciate it. I am now thinking it should be the first answer; 8x+4/(4x^2+4)^2 this is worth a lot of points so please tell me if I am on the right track haha

Comment: @user3247128:  Where would the "+4" come from in your proposed numerator (and why is there still no minus sign)?  A different way to go:  What error does each of the problem's answers expect/hope that you are making?

Comment: I can't seem to simplify this very well. I feel like the 8 should be negative but that isn't an option. Or am I just getting this completely wrong? Sorry to be a pain, this is an online class so I can't directly talk to the teacher, so I am struggling quite a bit.

Comment: You wrote "(4x^2) + (4) x (0) - (1) x (8x)" and meant $(4x^2 + 4) \cdot (0) - (1) \cdot (8x)$.  What does the "$\cdot (0)$" do to the first part?  What does the "$- (1)$" do to the second part?  What does that leave?  BTW: writing "x" for "times" when solving a problem containing $x$s may not be helping you.

Comment: Oh! Wow I confused myself writing it like that. So (4x^2+4)⋅0 would be 0, leaving -1⋅8x which would be -8x. I just noticed the small negative sign in the answers, so the answer should be -8/(4x^2 + 4)^2, is that right? Thanks again I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3247128:  Um...  "$-8\mathbf{x}/\dots$"...

Comment: That's what I meant! I need sleep. Or coffee. WOOPS. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate $\frac{1}{x}$, you get $\frac{-1}{x^2}$.

Thus by the chain rule, if you differentiate $\frac{1}{g(x)}$, you get $\frac{-1}{g(x)^2}\cdot g'(x)$.

Let $g(x) =4x^2+4$, and substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: the chain rule is for finding derivatives of functions that look like $g(h(x))$, where $g(u)$ and $h(x)$ are both differentiable functions.

In this case, note that
$$
\frac{1}{4x^2+4}=g(h(x)),
$$
where
$$
g(u)=\frac{1}{u}\qquad\text{and}\qquad h(x)=4x^2+4.
$$

Answer (score -1):

Therefore, the derivative is $$ \frac{d}{dx} \, \left( \frac{1}{4 \, x^2 + 4} \right) = \frac{8 x}{(4 \, x^2 + 4)^2}. $$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your posts.